Oracle select returning fast but binding in with class object in C# taking long time
Problem Description:
I'm experiencing a significant delay in data binding in C# when executing an Oracle query, despite the query itself being relatively fast in the SQL editor. The binding process takes over a minute, while the SQL query executes in about 25 seconds.
What I've Tried:
Connection Pooling: Implemented connection pooling but noticed no change in performance.
Command Timeout: Set command.CommandTimeout = 100 to ensure the command doesn't timeout prematurely.
Questions:
Could the delay be due to the way data is being read from the OracleDataReader?
Is there a more efficient way to handle the data binding process in C# for large datasets from Oracle?
Are there any Oracle-specific optimizations or settings I might be missing?
Code:
`using (var connection = new OracleConnection(_connectionString))
{
    await connection.OpenAsync();
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew(); // Start the timer

    using (var command = new OracleCommand(@"
        SELECT       
            NVL(REGEXP_SUBSTR(code_number, '[^|]+', 1, 1), 'N/A') AS cd1,
            NVL(REGEXP_SUBSTR(code_number, '[^|]+', 1, 2), 'N/A') AS cd2,
            NVL(REGEXP_SUBSTR(code_number, '[^|]+', 1, 3), 'N/A') AS cd3,
            NVL(REGEXP_SUBSTR(code_number, '[^|]+', 1, 4), 'N/A') AS cd4,
            NVL(REGEXP_SUBSTR(code_number, '[^|]+', 1, 5), 'N/A') AS cd5,
            NVL(REGEXP_SUBSTR(code_number, '[^|]+', 1, 6), 'N/A') AS cd6,
            NVL(REGEXP_SUBSTR(code_number, '[^|]+', 1, 7), 'N/A') AS cd7
        FROM (
            SELECT
                SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(code, '|') AS code_number,
                SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(name, '|') AS name_value
            FROM tb_cs_hierarchy_detail
            WHERE hierarchy_id = :ID AND version_number = :v1
            START WITH parent_code = -1
            CONNECT BY PRIOR code = parent_code
        )
    ", connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ID", 2));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("v1", 2));
        command.CommandTimeout = 100; // Adjust timeout if needed

        using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
        {
            var hidetails = new List<HDetail>(); // Initialize list
            var CI1 = reader.GetOrdinal("cd1");
            var CI2 = reader.GetOrdinal("cd2");
            var CI3 = reader.GetOrdinal("cd3");
            var CI4 = reader.GetOrdinal("cd4");
            var CI5 = reader.GetOrdinal("cd5");
            var CI6 = reader.GetOrdinal("cd6");
            var CI7 = reader.GetOrdinal("cd7");

            // Processing time is too much with below code          
            while (await reader.ReadAsync())
            {
                var obList = new HDetail
                {
                    cd1 = reader.GetString(CI1),
                    cd2 = reader.GetString(CI2),
                    cd3 = reader.GetString(CI3),
                    cd4 = reader.GetString(CI4),
                    cd5 = reader.GetString(CI5),
                    cd6 = reader.GetString(CI6),
                    cd7 = reader.GetString(CI7),
                };
                hidetails.Add(obList);
            }
        }
    }
    stopwatch.Stop(); // Stop the timer
    Console.WriteLine($"Query executed in: {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
}`


Where is the binding?  The binding may be running on an internal timers. To speed up binding set datasource to null and then back to the source which should immediately update the results.

// Processing time is too much with below code  see the code with this comment . That's where it taking too much time

When you say that the SQL query "executes in 25 seconds" in the SQL editor, are you certain that you are getting the time to fetch all the rows?  Most (effectively all) SQL editors will show you the first page of results as soon as those reach the client while the code you posted has to fetch all the rows to the end.  How many rows/ how much data does the query return?  Do you get the same plan for both queries (particularly if you are using literals in the SQL editor rather than bind variables)?

Yes I check the record count its perfect its a oracle query and on Toad the time is just 20 sec. records are like 3K but when it comes to  C# the binding to data object is taking more than 80 sec.

A SQL with bind variables is a different SQL than the same query with literals. You can't just pop such a query into Toad, replace the variables with test values, and expect to get similar performance. In one case the optimizer knows exactly which values you are interested in and can make more informed decisions about its plan at parse time, whereas in the other it is much more limited, as the bind value is not available at parse time. You will need to look at the wait interface (SQL Monitor, ASH, OEM, etc..) to see how your plan has changed and go from there.

But it could also be as simple as the others have suggested - you may not be timing the entire result set. Wrap it with select count(*) from ([query]) and test it that way in Toad. even then it's not an exact test for the reasons I explained, not to mention that throwing away columns at the top query block can cause optimizations that can change the plan as well. But it's much better than simply comparing how long it takes to see a page of results.

I have a class model to bind with the query result its fase on the line var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync() but after that when its binding the Object its taking like 90 sec which I dont understand why its happening

What is time if you do not use Async?

few sec like 4-5 sec improvement .
